# Hibernate replace string condition

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, orm

I'm having some trouble to create a query where a necessary condition is to use a like into a field where I need to replace a special character. Something like this:

```
public List<MyClass> search(Myclass object){

Criteria cri = criteria(MyClass.class);
if(object.getName() != null){
    cri.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("replace("+cri.getAlias()+".name,"+object.getSpecialCharacter()+", '') like '"+object.getName()+"'"));  
}
if(dominio.getType()!= null){
    cri.add(Restrictions.eq("type", object.getType()));
}
if(dominio.getWorkspace() != null){
    cri.add(Restrictions.eq("workspace", object.getWorkspace()));
}
if(dominio.getStatus() != null){
cri.add(Restrictions.eq("status", object.getStatus()));
}

return cri.list();

}
```

With this code I've got the error below:

```
this_.ID_MYCLASS as ID_MYCLASS1_33_0_,
this_.NM_MYCLASS as NM_MYCLASS4_33_0_,
this_.ID_STATUS as ID_STATU5_33_0_,
this_.ID_TYPE as ID_TYPE_7_33_0_,
this_.ID_WORKSPACE as ID_WORKS8_33_0_ 
from KDTB_MYCLASS this_ 
where replace(this.name,'_', '') like 'COD' 
and this_.ID_WORKSPACE=?
```

ORA-00904: "THIS"."NAME": invalid identifier

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this.name is a table column and you want to remove the "_" on its value?

Comment: The "_" is just an example. The special character can vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
cri.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("replace({alias}.name,"+object.getSpecialCharacter()+", '') like '"+object.getName()+"'"));
```

Comment: It worked to find the table's alias, but I'm still having trouble with the attribute "name", Hibernate is generating the following query now:

Comment: I need to know the attribute "name" alias. How can I discover It's alias?

ORA-00904: "THIS_"."NAME": invalid identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this as the first parameter of `sqlRestriction`:

```
 "replace("+cri.getAlias()+"_.name,"
```

Ultimately, you're pointing out that HQL doesn't support the replace routine. If you have more trouble, consider ditching Criteria & use a native SQL query for this.